# How to generate json data with group by in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table as shown below

[image: Table structure]

Adding table scripts below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempStudentJsonData](
    [StudentID] [int] NULL,
    [ClassID] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [DocumentID] [int] NULL,
    [DocumentChildID] [int] NULL,
    [UploadedFileName] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [documentname] [varchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And following are the test data.

```
INSERT [dbo].[TempStudentJsonData] ([StudentID], [ClassID], [DocumentID], [DocumentChildID], [UploadedFileName], [documentname]) VALUES (506995, N'CLASS-X', 5055, 0, N'P1.pdf', N'PHYSICS')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TempStudentJsonData] ([StudentID], [ClassID], [DocumentID], [DocumentChildID], [UploadedFileName], [documentname]) VALUES (506995, N'CLASS-X', 5058, 0, N'C1.pdf', N'CHEMISTRY')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TempStudentJsonData] ([StudentID], [ClassID], [DocumentID], [DocumentChildID], [UploadedFileName], [documentname]) VALUES (506995, N'CLASS-X', 5066, 387654, N'B1.pdf', N'BIOLOGY')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TempStudentJsonData] ([StudentID], [ClassID], [DocumentID], [DocumentChildID], [UploadedFileName], [documentname]) VALUES (506995, N'CLASS-X', 5066, 387655, N'B2.pdf', N'BIOLOGY')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TempStudentJsonData] ([StudentID], [ClassID], [DocumentID], [DocumentChildID], [UploadedFileName], [documentname]) VALUES (506995, N'CLASS-X', 5151, 387656, N'H1.pdf', N'HISTORY')
GO
```

From this table i want to generate a json as shown below

```
[
  {
    "StudentID": 506995,
    "documents": [
      {
        "documentname": "PHYSICS",
        "attachments": [
          {
            "attachmentname": "P1.pdf"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "documentname": "CHEMISTRY",
        "attachments": [
          {
            "attachmentname": "C1.pdf"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "documentname": "BIOLOGY",
        "attachments": [
          {
            "attachmentname": "B1.pdf"
          },
          {
            "attachmentname": "B2.pdf"

          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "documentname": "HISTORY",
        "attachments": [
          {
            "attachmentname": "H1.pdf"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am tried to generate json using the following query

```
SELECT [StudentID],            
          (
             SELECT documentname,                  
          (
             SELECT UploadedFileName    as attachmentname          
                              
             FROM TempStudentJsonData
              FOR JSON PATH
          ) AS attachments
             FROM TempStudentJsonData FOR JSON PATH
          ) AS documents
             FROM TempStudentJsonData group by [DocumentID],[StudentID]  FOR JSON PATH
```

and getting the result as follow

[image: tries]

How can i map only the desired uploaded files to respective document name (grouping the uploaded files to respective document name or document id)? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

..correlate the subquery for the documentnames(for each student) and then the documents(for each student&documentname)

```
 SELECT st.[StudentID],            
          (
          
             SELECT distinct dn.documentname,                  
          (
             SELECT uf.UploadedFileName    as attachmentname          
             FROM TempStudentJsonData as uf
             where uf.StudentId  = dn.StudentId
             and uf.DocumentId = dn.DocumentId
              FOR JSON PATH
          ) AS attachments
          FROM TempStudentJsonData as dn
          where dn.StudentId = st.StudentId
          FOR JSON PATH
          ) AS documents
FROM TempStudentJsonData as st 
group by st.[StudentID]  FOR JSON PATH
```

Comment: some problem with the group by it is giving multiple results.can you try the same sql fiddle?

Comment: ...@athuman..yes, i've just seen that...and edited the answer (get unique/group by students, for each student get the distinct document names, and for each document name get the correlated documents/files.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible approach is to use `FOR JSON AUTO` and the appropriate joins. As is [mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-json-output-automatically-with-auto-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) in the documentation, when *... you specify the AUTO option, the format of the JSON output is automatically determined based on the order of columns in the SELECT list and their source tables*.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   students.StudentID, 
   documents.DocumentName, 
   attachments.UploadedFileName AS attachmentname
FROM TempStudentJsonData students
JOIN TempStudentJsonData documents ON students.StudentID = documents.StudentID
JOIN TempStudentJsonData attachments ON students.StudentID = documents.StudentID AND documents.DocumentID = attachments.DocumentID
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Result:

```
[
   {
      "StudentID":506995,
      "documents":[
         {
            "DocumentName":"BIOLOGY",
            "attachments":[
               {"attachmentname":"B1.pdf"},
               {"attachmentname":"B2.pdf"}
            ]
         },
         {
            "DocumentName":"CHEMISTRY",
            "attachments":[
               {"attachmentname":"C1.pdf"}
            ]
         },
         {
            "DocumentName":"HISTORY",
            "attachments":[
               {"attachmentname":"H1.pdf"}
            ]
         },
         {
            "DocumentName":"PHYSICS",
            "attachments":[
               {"attachmentname":"P1.pdf"}
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```